# How to read $xyz value from .properties file in python?

Tags: python, properties, configparser

I have a `build.properties` file like

```
[directory]
src = src
srcdir = ${src}/fix
srcext = ${srcdir}/extensions
srct = ${srcext}/xyz
```

my aim is to get the full value of `srct` i mean it is to be `src/fix/extensions/xyz`

Is there any way of getting the value of cde? I tried `configparser` and `jproperties` but i couldn't get the required output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ExtendedInterpolation` class which implements more advanced syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation).

```
>>> from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation
>>> 
>>> parser = ConfigParser(interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())
>>> parser.read("build.properties")
['build.properties']
>>> print(parser["directory"]["srct"])
src/fix/extensions/xyz
```

Comment: i added a section like `[directory]` in properties files but it throughs an error

Comment: i got an error in `print` part ` raise `InterpolationMissingOptionError(`  error like `configparser.InterpolationMissingOptionError: Bad value substitution: option 'extensiondir' in section 'directory' contains an interpolation key 'srcbasedir' which is not a valid option name. Raw value: '${srcbasedir}/extensions'`

Comment: please check the edit the file is like that

Comment: I did test it and working fine for me. Can you also update the code you are trying with?

Comment: @niteshrijal Anyway I have edited my answer to sync with the updated file contents